# Nuxt.js and handle API 404 response for dynamic pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I use Nuxt.js and I have dynamic page `/items/{id}`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Item #{{ item.id }} &laquo;{{ item.title }}&raquo;</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { api } from '../../mo/api'

export default {
  asyncData({ params }) {
    return api(`items/${params.id}`)
  },
}
</script>
```

Backend API returns object {item: {id: .., title: "...", ...}}.
But if an item with specified ID not exist API returns 404 response.
And Vue crash with "[Vue warn]: Property or method "item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render."

How can I handle 404 response?

My `api.js` module:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export function api(url) {
  url = encodeURIComponent(url)
  return axios
    .get(`http://localhost:4444/?url=${url}`)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      return data
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // 404 catch there
    })
}
```

**Solution:**

Need to read manual: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#handling-errors

Comment: Initialize `item` with `null` or `undefined` and use `v-if` / `v-else`.

Comment: can I use standard 404 page from my project instead use v-if for all these situations?

Comment: Seen [this](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#handling-errors)?

Comment: yes. and didn't it work! but as usual now it work :)) thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please make sure to add the solution to your question or post it as an answer so that other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just execute error function :)

```html
<script>
export default {
  asyncData({ params, error }) {
    return axios
      .get(`https://my-api/posts/${params.id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        return { title: res.data.title }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Post not found' })
      })
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `fetch()` hook, this is how it should be written

```html
<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    try {
      await fetch('https://non-existent-website.commmm')
        .then((response) => response.json())
    } catch (error) {
      this.$nuxt.context.error({
        status: 500,
        message: 'Something bad happened',
      })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

More context available here: https://nuxtjs.org/announcements/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/#error-handling

Answer (score -6):

Need to read the manual: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/#handling-errors :)  .