# Nuxt 3 routing: dynamic routes 404

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am building an application that fetches data from an API.
If the API does not find the data I want to display a 404 page.

I have a catch-all route named `[...slug]` that fetches the data from the API, but how do I render a 404 page without redirecting if the API does not find the data. Redirection is probably the easy fix, but it is not the desired way to do it.

I have looked through https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/error-handling#errors-during-the-vue-rendering-lifecycle-ssr--spa.
But this looks more like a way to catch errors.

I have also seen the following post [Nuxt.js and handle API 404 response for dynamic pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500137/nuxt-js-and-handle-api-404-response-for-dynamic-pages). But using the asyncData and error does not seem to work in Nuxt 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
throw createError({
  statusCode: 404,
  message: 'not found',
  fatal: true
})
```

This will make sure it is also handled on static generated sites.

Comment: Thanks, this was not possible in the release candidate version that I was using

Answer (score 2):

You can show an error page programmatically in nuxt3 like this:

```js
throw createError({
  statusCode: 404,
  message: 'not found',
})
```

e.g.

```js
const { error } = useFetch(...)

if (error.value) {
  throw createError(...)  
}
```

Comment: that definitely throws a custom error. how could I render a 404.vue page in case of 404 error?

Comment: Create an `error.vue`: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/error-handling/#rendering-an-error-page

Comment: i think i got problem with Netlify not knowing about the 404 page as statically generated site. tried adding fallback: '404.html' but still got Netlify's default 404